# Data formatting issues; Is my function the problem?

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse, export-to-excel, rdcomclient

every day I get an email listing sales in a shop for the previous day.
My email looks like this:

```
Date of report:,15-JAN-2022
Time report produced:,16-JAN-2022 00:25


Service: 

$$s
Apples,5
Grapes,8
Grapefruit,6
Lemons,5
Oranges,1
Pears,2
Total,27
```

I've been able to put something together that runs through my outlook, finds the values in the email body and puts it all into a datatb:

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

search <- OutApp$AdvancedSearch("Inbox", "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = 'FRUIT SALES'")
Sys.sleep(5)
results <- search$Results()
results$Count()

getsales_vals <- function(email) {
  body <- email$body()
  date <- str_extract(body, "\\d{2}-[:alpha:]{3}-\\d{4}")[1] %>% 
    as.character()
  data <- read.table(text = body, sep = ",", skip = 7, strip.white = T) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = V1, values_from = V2) ## this line doesn't seem to do anything
    mutate("Date" = date)
  
  return(data)
}
info <- sapply(results, getsales_vals, simplify = F) %>% 
  bind_rows()

print(info)
```

When the 'print' runs I get this in the console:

```
$$s                                Date
Apples...1                         5 15-SEP-2021
Grapes...2                         8 15-SEP-2021
Grapefruit...3                     6 15-SEP-2021
Lemons...4                         5 15-SEP-2021
Oranges...5                        1 15-SEP-2021
Pears...6                          2 15-SEP-2021
Total...7                          27 15-SEP-2021
```

And if I write info to an xlsx I get this (| represents division between A and B column):

```
$$s | Date
5 | 15-JAN-2022
8 | 15-JAN-2022
6 | 15-JAN-2022
5 | 15-JAN-2022
1 | 15-JAN-2022
2 | 15-JAN-2022
27 | 15-JAN-2022
```

What I'd like to get is this (with the '$$s' dropped entirely):

```
Date | Apples | Grapes | Grapefruit | Lemons | Oranges | Pears | Total
 15-JAN-2022| 5 | 8 | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 27
```

I thought the use of 'pivot_wider' might achieve the desired result, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be having the desired effect.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove the `data` from the pivot_wider as you use `%>%` so it chains

Comment: I have already mentioned it before, but there is absolutely no reason to use asynchronous Application.AdvancedSearch if you are only searching in one folder - retrieve Inbox using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderItnbox) and synchronously call Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict. There will be no need for `Sys.sleep(5)`.